# CSS one column layout of relative width

Tags: html, css

I'd need my website layout to behave like this:

If the content div is wider than 50em, apply rules `width: 75%; max-width: 75em`.
Otherwise, `max-width: 50em; min-width: 25em` apply.

Primary reason for this setup are wide screen panels vs. laptops and mobiles. The content is always horizontally centered. If the div was always 75% wide, it would kill the layout on phones, and it would also make long, unreadable lines on wide screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use @media queries. They were made for things like this.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 50em) {
     #div { width: 75%; max-width: 75em; }
}
```

More info http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for are media-queries:

```
@media (min-width: 50em)
{ 
   div
   {
       width: 75%;
       max-width: 75em;
   }
}
```

The css-rules inside this media-query are only applied, if the **screen-width** is bigger than 50em. You can use as many media-queries as you want in your css.

Here are some more informations about this topic: http://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/CSS/Media_Queries

Answer (score 0):

Use the @media closure in your CSS ?

You may read this: http://help.campaignmonitor.com/topic.aspx?t=164